# how to restrict roles to accessing some of the pages in a web application

Tags: java

I have list of roles like, admin,tester, developer..etc.

And i have list of html pages for them (likely tabs...Deveoper , Test and Admin )

If i login with tester i don't want to give the access for testing tab and if i login as developer i don't want to give the access for testing tab.

If i log in as admin, i will have the access to all the pages like, admin,testing and developer tabs.

How to create a DB schema and where to place the permissions for the html pages..etc

Kindly suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you are using JSF, this might help you [Securing a JSF application with Java EE security and JBoss AS 7.x](http://martinsdeveloperworld.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/securing-a-jsf-application-with-java-ee-security-and-jboss-as-7-x/).

Comment: I suggest you read this article: http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security ;)

Answer (score 0):

one way to go:

```
Resource table:  the resources you want to do access control
permission table: resource, permission (read or write)
Role table
role_permission table: role-permission m:n relation
User_Role table: user-role m:n relation
User table
```

then when you program loads some resource, check if the user has the permission. (the permissions belong to the user could be saved in session object after login)

Comment: What will resource table contains? how to give permission in database for the pages?

Comment: @mail2kiru contains the objects that you want to have access control. E.g. Student, Person, or some page... You can have something like `pageOne, read`, when user request that resouce (pageOne), you check user's profile, if his role has the permission read/write, to do further process.

Comment: can you give me some sample code for above requirement?